# alter the audio input and output of a phone call in android

Tags: android, kotlin, audio, android-phone-call

I am trying to build a calling app that will pass the phone call audio output, input to and from the computer respectively.
For this, I am creating a server on a computer that will use WebSockets to communicate with the android device over WLAN.

But I am not able to find a way to get audio input and output from the phone call.

Any advice on how to approach this would be hugely appreciated.